# Weird behaviour of Z-Buffer

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, zbuffer, skybox

I'm using Deferred Shading method to render the scene, but I have a problem with a Skybox technique due to weird behaviour of Z-Buffer. I've created additional Framebuffer and attached 5 textures, one of which is being used as a depth buffer. First pass is a geometry pass, which fills the textures with needed data, second pass renders the final objects with textures and lightning applied to the main framebuffer, the last pass renders Skybox. The problem is Skybox being ignored (Z-Buffer check fails, so it is invisible).

When rendering a Skybox, I map the secondary framebuffer as a GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER and main framebuffer (screen) as a GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, so the depth buffer of the secondary framebuffer can be used, then I set the depth function to GL_LEQUAL. And only if I change depth function to GL_GREATER (or GL_ALWAYS) the Skybox can be seen, however it is being rendered on top of the objects.

The Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 Position;

uniform mat4 M;
uniform mat4 V;
uniform mat4 P;

out vec3 TexCoord0;

void main()
{
    vec4 MVP_Pos = P * V * M * vec4(Position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = MVP_Pos.xyww;
    TexCoord0 = Position;
}
```

Model matrix is a product of translation of the Skybox to the camera coordinates.

glDepthFunction set to GL_LEQUAL:
[image: GL_LEQUAL]

glDepthFunction set to GL_GREATER:
[image: GL_GREATER]

Contents of the Z-Buffer:
[image: Z-Buffer]

UPDATE 1: I've tried to use glBlitFramebuffer like that:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo); //Additional framebuffer
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);
```

But it doesn't work. Main depth buffer contains array of black pixels.

UPDATE 2:

```
//FBO initialization
glGenFramebuffers(1, &m_fbo);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);

// Create gbuffer textures
glGenTextures(ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(m_textures), m_textures);
glGenTextures(1, &m_depthTexture);

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(m_textures); i++) {
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[i]);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB32F, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, NULL);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + i, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[i], 0);
    }

// depth buffer
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthTexture);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT,
        NULL);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_depthTexture, 0);

GLenum DrawBuffers[] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT2, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT3 };
glDrawBuffers(ARRAY_SIZE_IN_ELEMENTS(DrawBuffers), DrawBuffers);

GLenum Status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);

if (Status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "FB error, status: 0x%x\n", Status);
    return false;
}
```

Skybox buffers:

```
GLfloat cube_vertices[] = {
        // front
        -1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, 1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, 1.0,
        // back
        -1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, -1.0, -1.0,
        1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
        -1.0, 1.0, -1.0,
    };

    GLushort cube_elements[] = {
        // front
        0, 1, 2,
        2, 3, 0,
        // top
        3, 2, 6,
        6, 7, 3,
        // back
        7, 6, 5,
        5, 4, 7,
        // bottom
        4, 5, 1,
        1, 0, 4,
        // left
        4, 0, 3,
        3, 7, 4,
        // right
        1, 5, 6,
        6, 2, 1,
    };
```

Comment: *the last pass renders Skybox* why? Can't you render the skybox first, then blend the other things on top? (Possibly clearing the depth, or disabling the depth test, etc.)

Comment: @peppe If the skybox is being drawn at the first pass, the shader will need to set every pixel on the screen, but at the last pass early depth-testing can give a huge speed boost, because usually only a small part of the skybox is visible.

Comment: I'd never expect that drawing a skybox is fill-rate limited...

Comment: @peppe: what else would you think a skybox render get limited by? It primarily uses fillrate. It's definitely a recommendation done by graphics vendors too. "No point doing work that's going to be thrown away". Why would you do that work first ?

Comment: Sure, but at the same time it's trivial most of the times. Anyhow, perhaps you can stencil it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When rendering a Skybox, I map the secondary framebuffer as a
>   `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` and main framebuffer (screen) as a
>   `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER`, so the depth buffer of the secondary framebuffer
>   can be used,

That is not how things work. The `GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER` is not relevant for the depth test. It is used as the source for opeations like `glReadPixels` or `glBlitFramebuffer`. But for any kind of rendering, only the `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER` is relevant. This includes the depth test.

Unfortuanly, you can't mix user-defined render targets like render buffers or textures with window-system provided buffers, so you just can't render to the final screen while using the specific depth test. So you either have to do an additional render pass to an FBO using the custom depth buffer, and blit the result to the screen, or you can blit the contents of the custom depth buffer to the window-system provided one and render with that.

Comment: Using glBlitFramebuffer was the first thing I've tried to do, however it doesn't work.

Comment: @romu4: Well, there is lot's of things which are still unclear, i.e. at which depth are you trying to draw the skybox, how you set up your FBO and depth buffer/texture and so on. This answer did focus on something which is definitively wrong in the approach described by the original question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added FBO initialization code and Skybox buffer contents to the main post. The texture buffers seem to work just fine, the only problem is the Z-Buffer, glBlitFramebuffer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Additional framebuffer had 32 bits/pixel, but main framebuffer had only 24, that prevented `glBlitFramebuffer` from working. So the proper Framebuffer initialization would look like that:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 0, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT,
        NULL);
```